# Why the factorial in this analytical form of Dirichlet function?

Tags: limits

On Mathworld I found that the Dirichlet function can be [written as](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html)

$D(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(m!\pi x)$

Is the exclamation mark a factorial and why do you need it there? Why can't you absorb this monotonic function into the limit?

Answer (score 1):

The factorial is necessary because otherwise the outer limit may not exist. Say $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Then the inner limit (if $m!$ is replaced by $m$) would fluctuate depending on $m$, sometimes being $1$ and other times being $0$, depending on whether $m$ is a multiple of $2$.

With the current form with $m!$, once $xM!$ is an integer for some $M$, for all $m\ge M$, $xm!$ is also an integer. That's why this works.

To answer your question about why this can't be absorbed into the limit, note that this limit is the limit of a sequence, not that of a function. $m$ can only take integral values. While it's impossible for the limit of a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ to be distinct from the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$, this only applies if $(a_n)$ actually converges. It's possible for $(a_{n_k})$ to converge and not $(a_n)$, which is what happens here.